# Passing controller to this.render in an Ember route renderTemplate hook

Tags: ember.js

This is a question about Ember fundamentals.

Let's consider the following code from the [Transitioning to Show Only Incomplete Todos](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/show-only-incomplete-todos/) step of the official Ember Getting Started guide.

```
Todos.TodosActiveRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.filter('todo', function(todo) {
      return !todo.get('isCompleted');
    });
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller) {
    this.render('todos/index', {controller: controller});
  }
});
```

`this.render` is defining the passed object `controller` as its controller. This makes sense as far as it goes, but... why?

The application (seems to) work if we call `this.render` with only the template name argument:

```
  renderTemplate: function(controller) {
    this.render('todos/index');
  }
```

The [renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) documentation states that it uses the route's controller by default, and that its `controller` argument is also set to the route's controller. The pattern in the tutorial seems to explicitly declare default behavior. What's going on here?

Comment: The presence or absence of an unused function parameter by definition can have no effect, so I'm highly doubtful that in fact `function(controller)` would do something different from just `function()` in this case. You're using the expression "we pass `controller` to `renderTemplate`", but you're not passing anything--you're just declaring, or not declaring, a function argument, which as I had said will have no effect whatsoever if the argument is not used.

Comment: ditto, and proof http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fisehuwi/1/edit

Comment: I've edited the question to eliminate potential confusion caused by my questionable diagnostic skills. Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible causes,

1. When the guide was written it didn't apply the route's controller when no controller was specified
2. The person who wrote that guide didn't realize that the route's controller would be applied when one wasn't specified
3. They wanted to verbosely state they were using the controller for the fun of it

Trek did March 16 2013, https://github.com/emberjs/website/commit/0f2af23799ee2ba3c643303fb96e8b72026f8e7f#diff-750a8e7208fb50dc62974ff56234d69e

And it looks like the functionality was added January 10, 2013 by nragaz
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/dbe5b4fbcb26fc030cd4fb9fa5ae586217f20a4e

So it looks like I was wrong about #1, and it was probably #2.